# How can I round /scan topic values?

Tags: ros, lidar, ros-kinetic, scan, topic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!
I am student and I really want to send /scan topic values to rtabmapviz. I am using ROS kinetic, /scan is topic created by RPLidarNode. Unfortunately I think that I need rounded values, because I really don't need 8 digit numbers. Do I have to create my own node to round those values, or is there another nice and fast way to do that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/340214/how-can-i-round-/scan-topic-values?/) by [tominkoooo](https://answers.ros.org/users/50353/tominkoooo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-12-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could:

- Modify the rp lidar driver to round in the way you'd like
- Create a laser filter to round the values
- Create a node between the rp lidar node and rtab-map to round the values and publish /scan_rounded
- Modify rtab map itself

Many options :-)

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2019-12-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tominkoooo](https://answers.ros.org/users/50353/tominkoooo/) on 2019-12-17**:
Okay, I just rediscovered that I cannot round float, so nothing can be done. Anyway, thank you for response! :)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-12-18**:
`float` can certainly be rounded.

But we seem to be ignoring something important here: *why* do you have the impression that you need to "round[ed] values"? I've not seen questions about this before on this forum.